# What kind of cactus is this?

Tags: identification, succulents, cactus

[image: photo]

I just bought this plant but I am now realizing that I have no idea what it is, so looking up care tips is much more difficult than anticipated. Would you be able to help me identify it?

Comment: No, this is not a cactus. Cactus don't have veined leaves. Interesting looking plant, though.

Comment: Ah, a Euphorbia! Keep in mind that the sap is an irritant/toxin.

Comment: @TimNevins I discovered it was an irritant yesterday the unfortunate way, I appreciate the warning

Comment: Be careful with that stuff. Especially around your eyes! At least the plant looks nice though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a succulent from the *Euphorbia* genus (which are not cacti, like Tim Nevins already mentioned).

I think this could be *Euphorbia milii* f. *lutea* or [Yellow Crown of Thorns](https://worldofsucculents.com/euphorbia-milii-lutea-yellow-crown-thorns/).

It wants lots of sun and not too much water. Originates from Madagascar.

Answer (score 1):

**Maybe** some type of [Pereskia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pereskia), although better pictures of the spines & flower would help. Species *Pereskia grandifolia* commonly called ["Rose Cactus"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pereskia_grandifolia). I know nothing about the care of these plants, but a google search turned up [This](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/rose-cactus-75744.html).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a plant I know by the name "corona de Cristo" or "Christ's crown". I agree with user @b.nota, they seem to have correctly identified it.
I cross-searched it with the spanish name and the scientific name and the same results popped up.

Comment: AKA crown of thorns